# Installing anaconda to use with windows

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, anaconda

I am lost in the installation process of installing anaconda on windows.

I've installed the windows 32bit package (I'm running windows 7 x64)

I have anaconda in the start menu and I can open the python console and use scipy.stats.t.interval(), the function I am interested in.

However, how do I go about including this in another python program? I think it's something like adding it to the path. For instance, I have the scipy.stats.t.interval() function call in my other python file which I run through cygwin via `python myscript.py`. However it returns the error:

```
from scipy.stats import t
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats
```

I think it might be a change of path / add to path issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it :/. While I try to fix it, I figure I will post for help here.

Answer (score 2):

well you might have two installations of python, one inside the anaconda package, and other which you might have installed earlier. try doing :

```
which python
```

from CygWin console.
If it returns:

```
/usr/bin
```

then it is definitely a add-to-path problem.
to fix it for CygWin,
you have to add the python installation from anaconda to the path.

try this fromn CygWin:

```
PATH=path-where-anaconda-is-installed/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

and then doing:

```
which python
```

should give you:

```
/path-to-anaconda/anaconda/bin
```

and then it will work.

Cheers

Comment: OP is using CygWin, and it emulates unix terminal, and supports .rc files