# Permanently set Python path for Anaconda within Cygwin

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, anaconda

I'm trying to install Anaconda on my Windows 7 machine. I often use cygwin to for my command-line work, and I would like to manage Anaconda from there. I've worked through the graphic installer without any issues, and checked necessary boxes to reset my default path to this install of python. I go ahead to check where python is and initially I get this...

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

From here python works fine...

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct  2 2013, 22:34:09)
[GCC 4.8.1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

But I'm trying to work from anaconda, so I should just need to redefine my path...

```
$ export PATH=/cygdrive/c/anaconda:$PATH
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/anaconda/python
```

And now I should be good to go, but when I try and step into python, it just hangs

```
$ python
```

Any idea why this might be happening? verbose return, below...

```
$ python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# C:\anaconda\lib\site.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\site.py
import site # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\site.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\os.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\os.py
import os # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import nt # builtin
# C:\anaconda\lib\ntpath.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\ntpath.py
import ntpath # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\ntpath.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\stat.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\stat.py
import stat # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\stat.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\genericpath.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\genericpath.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\warnings.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\warnings.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\linecache.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\linecache.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\types.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\types.py
import types # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\types.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\UserDict.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\UserDict.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\_abcoll.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\_abcoll.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\abc.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\abc.py
import abc # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\abc.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\_weakrefset.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# C:\anaconda\lib\copy_reg.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\copy_reg.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\traceback.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\traceback.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\sysconfig.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\sysconfig.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\re.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\re.py
import re # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\re.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\sre_compile.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# C:\anaconda\lib\sre_parse.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\sre_parse.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\sre_constants.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\sre_constants.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\locale.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\locale.py
import locale # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\locale.pyc
import encodings # directory C:\anaconda\lib\encodings
# C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\__init__.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\__init__.pyc
# C:\anaconda\lib\codecs.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\aliases.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\aliases.pyc
import operator # builtin
# C:\anaconda\lib\functools.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\functools.py
import functools # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\functools.pyc
import _functools # builtin
import _locale # builtin
# C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyc matches C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py
import encodings.cp1252 # precompiled from C:\anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.pyc
# zipimport: found 13 names in C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\runipy-0.1.0-py2.7.egg
# zipimport: found 144 names in C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-3.6-py2.7.egg
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and htt
```

Another (possibly related) issue I'm having is needing to reset the path every time I close/open cygwin. I've entered the following text into .bashrc and .profile to try and set the path permanently:

```
# Set path to python from anaconda install
export PATH=/cygdrive/c/anaconda:$PATH
```

After opening and closing cygwin, I return to:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Could this be related to setting certain system environment variables?

Answer (score 29):

To work with the interactive Python shell in Cygwin I use the -i option.

To get it from the Anaconda install, I used the steps suggested above:

```
$ export PATH=/cygdrive/c/anaconda:$PATH
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/anaconda/python
```

Then I launch python within Cygwin with the -i option:

```
$ python -i
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:12:11) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>>>
```

The libraries are also working fine. For instance the pandas library (which has been installed through Anaconda) can be imported now.

```
>>>> import pandas
>>>> pandas.DataFrame
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Now to make this permanent I added the path in my bashrc file:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=/cygdrive/c/anaconda:$PATH' >> .bashrc
$ source .bashrc
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/anaconda/python
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. Still had the problem of my .bashrc file not running automatically at startup, so I added ". ~/.bashrc" (without the quotes) to ~/.bash_profile and now it's working like a charm (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815927/cygwin-shell-doesnt-execute-bashrc)

Comment: Explanation of the `-i` option: `-i When a script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script or the command, even when sys.stdin does not appear to be a terminal. The PYTHONSTARTUP file is not read. This can be useful to inspect global variables or a stack trace when a script raises an exception. See also PYTHONINSPECT.` https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

Answer (score 5):

I too was having an issue getting anaconda set up with my Cygwin / Windows 7 system.  What worked was the following:

1. Edited the ~/.bashrc. Add below to the bottom of file.

   `export PATH=/cygdrive/c/Anaconda:$PATH`
2. This mapped Cygwin's python to the anaconda distribution as proof by entering `which python` in Cygwin's console.  However, when launching python it would hang up forcing me to ^C out of the command.  I found that `python -i` will launch the interactive python interpreter with no issues.

Comment: Thanks @SciGuyMcQ I have solved the problem above by changing the path in .bashrc files but export PATH=/cygdrive/c/Users/User/anaconda3:$PATH probably the path was not right as Python version 3 onwards using anaconda3 instead of conda

Answer (score 3):

### Path

Regarding your path issue, see [Installing anaconda to use with windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244540/installing-anaconda-to-use-with-windows) on how to fix that.   Alternatively, you can just run `/cygdrive/c/Anaconda/python.exe` to start the Anaconda/windows python and leave the standard `python` pointing to the cygwin version.

Note that few of the suggestions given on the internet also include the necessary change to `PYTHONPATH`: if you use the anaconda/windows python, you also want the anaconda python libraries.  Binary modules like `numpy` will surely crash or misbehave if you mix things up.  The easiest way to check this is to install a module in cygwin that you do not need in Conda and test whether you can import that from anaconda python.  If you can, your path is wrong.

Anaconda python will automatically add `c:\Anconda` to your PYTHONPATH, but if you have it set to serve CYGWIN python libraries, those will be found before the Anaconda libs.  Try

```
import sys
sys.path
```

### Terminal

However,  this is also a terminal issue:  Anaconda (Windows) python expects a windows shell and a modern cygwin shell is like an `xterm`, so very different.  Diagnose this by running `python --help`, if that works but plain `python` hangs, the interactive prompt is the problem.  This means you can run python programs, you just cannot interact with them.

A way around this is to use the `cygwin bash shell` instead of the `cygwin terminal` (both are under Cygwin group in the Start menu).  They look very similar, but the font in the bash shell is less pretty and you cannot make the window wider than 80 chars (like all other CMD windows, never understood that 'feature').   This is cygwin bash running inside a CMD window, and your anaconda python will be interactive.  The `cygwin terminal` gives you a bash shell running in a putty derivative, which mimics an xterm and cannot be used by anaconda python.

Comment: My cygwin install doesn't have the cygwin bash shell to get the equivalent, run cmd.exe from windows start menu then run bash from there. It does fix the anaconda interaction problem.

Comment: Very useful post, thanks!  @poleguy, cygwin no longer installs a start-menu shortcut, but if you look in e.g. `C:\cygwin64` there should be a file `Cygwin.bat` to get an old-skool (no unicode!?) console. You can create a shortcut to that.

Answer (score 3):

There is another problem with conda's interpretation of cygwin. When you source the activation script for an environment, it prepends e.g.

> /C/Users/Thomas.Harris/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/envs/blah
>   /C/Users/Thomas.Harris/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/envs/blah/Library/mingw-w64/bin
>   /C/Users/Thomas.Harris/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/envs/blah/Library/usr/bin
>   /C/Users/Thomas.Harris/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/envs/blah/Library/bin
>   /C/Users/Thomas.Harris/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/envs/blah/Scripts

to your PATH. However, these are not proper directories in cygwin.

I fixed this with

`ln -s /cygdrive/c /C`

and then if you create conda environments with specific versions of python they should work.

Comment: `pip` is also messed up when using conda environemnts; take this into account if you need to install packages outside conda

Answer (score 1):

Regarding setting your path permanently, [edit the .profile in your home directory](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-files.html) (it's a hidden file).

> .profile (other names are also valid, see the bash man page) contains bash commands. It is executed when bash is started as login shell.

At the bottom of this file, put your set path command:

```
export PATH=/cygdrive/c/anaconda:$PATH
```

As for why python is hanging, please provide more information - for example what's the output of `python -v`?

Comment: Edited the original post. Still no luck setting the path permanently. Included verbose return of python initialization.

Comment: Please copy what you put into `.profile` to `.bashrc` instead. Also, does "regular" python start up (`/usr/bin/python`) ?

Comment: Updated original post. "regular" python works okay. I have the path definition added to .bashrc already, with no luck

Comment: You can also try creating a fresh conda environment with just Python. `conda create -n test python`, and then try `/cygdrive/c/anaconda/envs/test/python`.

Comment: I'm also having trouble running Anaconda (i)python inside of Cygwin.  I get the same (truncated, then hanging) behavior when running "python -v".  Did you manage to resolve this issue?  In my case I don't seem to have a problem with PATH.  Each time I open a cygwin terminal it has correct "which ipython" using Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late in coming to this, but I was having the same problem as you @thomasshouler. Try adding the export line below to the end of the .bash_profile and .profile files as well as your .bashrc file (as mentioned above). Make sure to    "source .bash_profile" etc for each file.

```
export PATH=/cygdrive/c/anaconda:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that for Anaconda 4, do:

```
vim /home/[Username]/.bash_profile
```

Append to the last line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Users/[Username]/Anaconda3/Scripts/
```

This solution worked for me as the usual anaconda3/bin could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

Once the Cygwin path is updated as mentioned above, you can also add an alias in the .bashrc file:

```
alias python='python -i'
```

This will bring up the Anaconda python interpreter in interactive mode from a Cygwin bash prompt