# Cygwin + Anaconda not working properly on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, anaconda

I will first say that I am a Linux and Mac guy and for working reasons I have been "forced" to work on Windows, Windows 7 more specifically. This is practically the first time I ever use Windows.

I first installed Anaconda (I though it would be the easiest way given my lack of experience in Windows) and then Cygwin, just running the defaults from `setup-x86_64.exe` file.

I can start python and Ipython in the commander (`cmd.exe`), so for example

```
C:\Users\username> ipython
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details. 

In [1]: import os 
In [2]: import sys
In [3]: os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
Out[4]: 'C:\\Anaconda3'
```

but this will not work in cygwin. It looks like Cygwin finds the correct installation (?)

```
username@AELAP3ZZ5662 /
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/Anaconda3/python

username@AELAP3ZZ5662 /
$ which ipython
/cygdrive/c/Anaconda3/Scripts/ipython
```

But when I start python it freezes completely and for Ipython:

```
$ ipython
In [1]:
```

There is no initialisation message and auto-completion, arrow-up and other usual ipython features will not work.

Anyway, any advise on how to set up anaconda with Cygwin? I am pretty sure all is about to edit a `PATH` or install something with the `setup-x86_64.exe` file, but Windown and I seem not to relate very well (so far).

Thanks

Comment: likely https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ok, so is either python within cygwin, or it will not work...fantastic...¬¬

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it with the -i flag? It doesn't work for me otherwise:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: <it hangs right here...>
```

When I run with -i:

```
$ ipython -i
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import os

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
Out[3]:
'C:\\Anaconda3'
```

My terminal crashes as soon as I exit when using `ipython`, but works fine if I use `python` instead. I know you posed this question a while ago, but if you are still interested [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255407/permanently-set-python-path-for-anaconda-within-cygwin) may be useful to you.