# How to use conda within cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, conda, miniconda

I have Win 7 with Cygwin installed. The cygwin has its own Python 2.7 interpreter. I have installed Miniconda separately for Win 7 (not for Cygwin, not sure if i have to).

So, the thing is I am able to create a new env from cygwin, and able to activate it. However, the activation doesn't seem to do anything??

```
ambarik@AMBARIK-WS01 ~
$ conda create -n cce python
Fetching package metadata: ..
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Miniconda\envs\cce:

The following packages will be linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.8               |                0   hard-link

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |#################################################| 100%
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > activate cce
#

ambarik@AMBARIK-WS01 ~
$ activate cce
-bash: activate: command not found

ambarik@AMBARIK-WS01 ~
$ /cygdrive/c/Miniconda/Scripts/activate.bat cce
Activating environment "cce"...

ambarik@AMBARIK-WS01 ~
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

How can i use conda within cygwin to install a python package?

**UPDATE1:** I understand that I manually change the python path to the conda/python/ like described here [Installing anaconda to use with windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244540/installing-anaconda-to-use-with-windows), but i was looking to see if there are other ways, other than manually modifying the path

**UPDATE2:** I am trying to actually install pexpect. I realized that the python that gets installed through cygwin comes with resource.dll. However, Python that gets installed via MiniConda doesn't come with it.

Comment: i think the solution could be somewhat like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969824/using-anaconda-environments-with-cygwin-on-windows, especially if your cygwin have precedence over windows binaries in the PATH. Yet my desire is to have it in some more simple way.

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed with the Conda 4.1 release.  Keep an eye out - coming soon.

Comment: Just trying with Miniconda 4.3.11. `source activate` works, but it sets the CONDA_PREFIX and correspondingly some directories in PATH to `/C/...` rather than `/cygdrive/c/...`.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin will probably work with the Unix [activate](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/bin/activate) and [deactivate](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/bin/deactivate) scripts. Try putting them in Anaconda\Scripts and use `source activate envname` and `source deactivate`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. As I don't as I get the following expected error `Error: no such directory: C:\Miniconda\envs\testenv\bin`. I am going to try to install the linux version of conda in cygwin, not sure how though?!

Comment: Installing the Linux version of conda into cygwin will not work, because the binaries themselves still need to be compiled for Windows.

Comment: Yes, i just tried it from the cygwin shell running `$ ./Miniconda-3.5.5-Linux-x86.sh` and i get error `cannot execute native linux-32 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 AMBARIK-WS01 1.7.30(0.272/5/3) 2014-05-23 10:36 i686 Cygwin`. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the cmd shell, where `activate` does work. You'll need to make sure to add cygwin to your PATH, though.