# Installing bedtools with conda (Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have been trying to install bedtools in Anaconda2 environment in Windows 10 and I got this error for these 3 channels. Anybody knows what is happening and why I can not install it?

```
(py36) C:\Users\User>conda install -c bioconda bedtools  
(py36) C:\Users\User>conda install -c cgat bedtools  
(py36) C:\Users\User>conda install -c biobuilds bedtools     

Solving environment: failed     
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - bedtools                    
Current channels:                 
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64                         
- https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch                         
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64                      
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch                      
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64                         
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch                         
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64                         
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch                         
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64                            
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch                            
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64                          
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch                          
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64                        
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch                        
- https://conda.anaconda.org/cgat/win-64                             
- https://conda.anaconda.org/cgat/noarch                             
- https://conda.anaconda.org/biobuilds/win-64                        
- https://conda.anaconda.org/biobuilds/noarch                                      

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, 
navigate to https://anaconda.org and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 0):

on bedtools conda page https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bedtools it only support linux or osx. 
So does bedtools page https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/installation.html

workarounds:

```
1. https://hub.docker.com/r/biocontainers/bedtools/    **Simplest, need install Docker.** 
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969824/using-anaconda-environments-with-cygwin-on-windows   **Complicate, if really need use windows.** 
3. Install VirtualBox and run linux and conda. **For long term solution if you need other bioinformatics analysis.**
```